# CSS styling navigation bar with short vertical lines

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

As mentioned above I'm trying to get result like described in the title but for a better explanation here is my idea [idea_prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isRs4.png). I tried the basic css which has been provided here but my expectations are slightly different.
Current outcome: [navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYUx6.png)

HTML code:
[HTML <- sorry Stack is not letting me add this as a code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWZCI.png)

CSS code:

```
nav {
  width: 1300px auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:white;
  border-radius: 10% / 100%

}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 18px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: sharing your html code will help :D

Comment: Can u share HTML as well, and create a snippet of it?

Comment: Hi, sorry. Stack was against me :) I had to uploaded as a picture but at least its not long :) Thank you!

Comment: why you put that div with class vl in your code?

Comment: sorry I was trying to figure out the lines by myself so i created extra div, however its not connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy, you dont even need that div with class vl, my thinking is that you put that div for the vertical line on the right, but there is no need of that, you can make that line with css property `border-right`

```css
nav ul {
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
nav ul li {width: 100%;text-align: center; }
nav ul li:not(:last-child){border-right: 1px solid #888;}
nav ul li a {text-decoration: none; color: #333;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">experience</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Plans</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Portafolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: if this helps you , dont forget to mark this the right answer